# Add filter conditions in PowerApps Filter dynamically

Tags: filter, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-selected-items

I have a combo box and in the filter formula one of my conditions is to filter records from a SQL data source where the column value is same as the one selected in the combo box. I have implemented that. Then the requirement changed to make it the combo box a multi-select one. My first thought was to use the 'IN' operator however there were delegation issues. So to circumvent this, I was thinking if there is a way to mock the behaviour of → Column1 in (Value1, Value2, Value3), where values are the selected items of combo box into something akin to →  (Column1 = Value1 or Column1 = Value2 or Column1 = Value3). In worst case, the user could select upto 40 values.

So my question is - Is there a way to form the filter conditions dynamically maybe using a ForAll, Concat etc.?